# Build column of data frame with character vectors of different length?

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to create a data frame in `R`.
To make an easy 2x2 example of my problem:

Assume the first column is a simple vector:

```
first <- c(1:2)
```

The second column is for every row a character vector (but of different length), for example:

`c('A')` for the first row and `c('B','C')` for the second.

How can I build this data frame?

Comment: Try `data.frame(first = 1:2, Second = I(list("A", c("B", "C"))))` maybe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to store different vector sizes in each row of a certain column, you will need to use a `list`, problem that (from `?data.frame`)

> If a list or data frame or matrix is passed to data.frame it is as if
>   each component or column had been passed as a separate argument

Thus you will need to wrap it up into `I` in order to protect you desired structure, e.g.

```
df <- data.frame(first = 1:2, Second = I(list("A", c("B", "C"))))
str(df)
# 'data.frame':  2 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ first : int  1 2
# $ Second:List of 2
# ..$ : chr "A"
# ..$ : chr  "B" "C"
# ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "AsIs"
```

Comment: If I apply the function `View` to the data frame the output is still of the form c('A','B'). Is there also a possibility to get only 'A' 'B' (without the c())?

Comment: It's because it's a list, see `df[2, 2]` for instance. You will need to do `df[2, 2][[1]]` or `unlist(df[2, 2])` if you want the actual values.